# Product of Baire spaces

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Hi¡ I have troubles with the next exercise. I'm so stuck. Any hint?

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be a Baire spaces. Prove that if $X\times Y$ is of second category in itself, then, $X\times Y$ is a Baire space.

I have some ideas, but, really I don't know how can I conclude. First, I thought in the definition. I take $\{ U_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a family of open and dense sets in $X\times Y$. Because $X\times Y$ is of second category in itself, we can conclude that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n\neq\emptyset$. We need to prove now that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n$ is a dense set in $X\times Y$. By contradiction, if we take a non empty open set $V$ of $X\times U$ such that $V\cap\left( \displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n\right)=\emptyset$, then, take a basic open $A\times B\subseteq V$. In this way, $(A\times B)\cap\left( \displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n\right)=\emptyset$. I think that $\Pi_{X}\left[ \displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n\right]$ (projection over $X$) is a dense set in $X$ and $\Pi_{Y}\left[ \displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n\right]$ (projection over $Y$) is a dense set in $Y$. In this way we obtain the desired contradiction because both pojections intersects $A$ and $B$ and then, $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n$ intersects $V$. But I don't know how can I prove the density of the projections (is it true?)
The other way is prove that every open set of $X\times Y$ is of second category in $X\times Y$. Again, by contradiction. Suposse that there exist $V$ open set in $X\times Y$ such that $V$ is of firts category in $X\times Y$, then, $V=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C_n$ with every $C_n$ a nowhere dense set. I think then that the projection of $V$ over $X$ is again a first category set, but this will be a contradiction (clearly, if it is true). 
Any hint? I really appreciate any help you can provide me.

Comment: What book is this exercise from? I find it hard to believe.

Comment: Suppose $X_0$ and $Y_0$ are Baire spaces such that $X_0\times Y_0$ is not a Baire space. Let $X=X_0+\mathbb R$ (topological sum) and let $Y=Y_0+\mathbb R.$ It seems to me that $X$ and $Y$ are Baire spaces, and $X\times Y$ is not a Baire space, but is of the second category in itself (if I understand what that means). What am I missing?

Comment: I don't know of what book it that exercise. My assessor gave me to study Baire properties. And, from your second comment, how you know that $X_0+\mathbb{R}$ is a Baire space and $X\times Y$ is of the second category itself?

Comment: Please remind me. What are the definitions of "Baire space" and "second category in itself"?

Comment: $X$ is a Baire space if for every sequence $\{U_n\}$ of open and dense sets of $X$, we have that $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n$ is a dense set of $X$. Now, $A\subseteq X$ is of first category if there exist $\{F_n\}$ a sequence of nowhere dense subsets of $X$ such that $A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}F_n$. Then, $A$ is of second category on $X$ if $A$ is not of first category.

Comment: Why is $X=X_0+\mathbb R$ a Baire space? Suppose $U_n$ is open and dense in $X.$ Then $U_n\cap X_0$ is open and dense in $X_0,$ and $U_n\cap\mathbb R$ is open and dense in $\mathbb R.$ Since $X_0$ and $\mathbb R$ are Baire spaces, $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}(U_n\cap X_0)$ is dense in $X_0$ and $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}(U_n\cap\mathbb R)$ is dense in $\mathbb R.$ It follows that $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}U_n=\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}(U_n\cap X_0)\right)\cup\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}(U_n\cap\mathbb R)\right)$ is dense in $X.$

Comment: Why is $X\times Y$ of the second category in itself? Suppose $X\times Y$ is of the first category in itself. Then $X\times Y=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}F_n$ where $F_n$ is a nowhere dense subset of $X\times Y.$ Since $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ is open in $X\times Y,$ it follows that $F_n\cap(\mathbb R\times\mathbb R)$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R.$ But this means that $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ is of the first category in itself, contradicting the Baire category theorem.

Comment: Wow. Now it is clear for me, but, really I can't see why $X\times Y$ is not a Baire space. Sorry, but I'm new in this topic.

Comment: I assumed that $X_0\times Y_0$ was not a Baire space. Now $X_0\times Y_0$ is open in $X\times Y,$ and an open subspace of a Baire space is a Baire space, so $X\times Y$ can't be a Baire space.

Comment: If you want, put the comments like an answer. I will accept.

Comment: I haven't really answered the question, because I haven't given an example of Baire spaces $X_0$ and $Y_0$ whose product is not a Baire space. I'm sure such spaces exist, but I don't remember how they are constructed and I don't feel like looking them up. If you want, you can write an answer to your own question, using my comments in any way you find useful.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-055-01/S0002-9939-1976-0401480-4/S0002-9939-1976-0401480-4.pdf Theorem 2.3, page 121

Comment: Great! Now you have everything you need to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is thanks to the user [bof](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/111012/bof):

Suppose $X_0$ and $Y_0$ are Baire spaces such that $X_0\times Y_0$ is not a Baire space. Such spaces there exist by [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-055-01/S0002-9939-1976-0401480-4/S0002-9939-1976-0401480-4.pdf), Theorem 2.3, page 121. Let $X=X_0+\mathbb{R}$ (topological sum) and let $Y=Y_0+\mathbb{R}$. $X$ is a Baire space. Suposse $U_n$ is open and dense in $X$. Then $U_n\cap X_0$ is open and dense in $X_0$, and $U_n\cap \mathbb{R}$ is open and dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $X_0$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are Baire spaces, $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(U_n\cap X_0 \right)$ is dense in $X_0$ and $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left( U_n\cap\mathbb{R}\right)$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. If follows that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n=\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(U_n\cap X_0 \right)\right)\cup\left( \displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left( U_n\cap\mathbb{R}\right)\right)$ is dense in $X$.

Now, $X\times Y$ is of second category in itself. Suposse $X\times Y$ is of the first category in itself. Then, $X\times Y=\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}F_n$ where $F_N$ is a nowhere dense subset of $X\times Y$. Since $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is open in $X\times Y$, it follows that $F_n\cap\left(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\right)$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$. But this means that $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ is of the first category in itself, contradicting the Baire category theorem.

Finally, I assumed that $X_0\times Y_0$ was not a Baire space. Now, $X_0\times Y_0$ is open in $X\times Y$, and an open subspace of a Baire space is a Baire space, so $X\times Y$ can't be a Baire space.